# Regex in Windows Batch to automate Docker run

Tags: regex, windows, amazon-web-services, docker, batch-file

I am trying to automate the process of sending my temporary Amazon AWS keys as environment variables to a Docker image using Windows. I have a file, *credentials.txt* that contains my AWS credentials (the 3 ids are always the same, but the string values change regularly). I am using Windows command prompt.

**Input**:
(includes 2 empty lines at end) *credentials.txt*:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id     = STR/+ing1
aws_secret_access_key = STR/+ing2
aws_session_token     = STR/+ing3
```

**Desired output**:
I need to issue the following command in order to run a Docker image (substituting the strings with the actual strings):

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=STR/+ing1 -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=STR/+ing2 -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=STR/+ing3 my-aws-container
```

**My idea** is to try to use regex on *credentials.txt* to convert it to:

```
SET aws_access_key_id=STR/+ing1
SET aws_secret_access_key=STR/+ing2
SET aws_session_token=STR/+ing3
```

And then run:

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%aws_access_key_id% -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%aws_secret_access_key% -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%aws_session_token% my-aws-container
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: Batch files can only utilize the poor regex implementation of findstr.exe, enter `findstr /?` at the Command Prompt to read its usage information. Other than that you should use an alternative language with proper regex support. The decision would probably be dependent upon the possible characters used in defining the values of your three variables. Effectively we'd need to know those character sets, in order to recommend a batch file solution using `findstr.exe`.

Comment: @Compo - I'll have a go with writing a python script and calling that script from Command Prompt. That's probably better than an ugly batch script anyways. The character set within the current strings is [0-9A-Za-z+/] (not sure if that's a proper regex character set, but digits, letters, and characters + and /)

Comment: Those characters do not present an issue with cmd or findstr, so there's still an opportunity for a batch file solution using those. Thank you for your confirmation.

Comment: Your suggestion of using an alternative language works. I've posted an answer below that uses python. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse your `credentials.txt` with a `for /f` loop to set the variables (effectively removing the spaces):

```
for /f "tokens=1,3" %%a in ('type credentials.txt ^| find "="') do set "%%a=%%b"
```

and then run the last code line from your question:

```
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%aws_access_key_id% -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%aws_secret_access_key% -e AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%aws_session_token% my-aws-container
```

Note: the values should not contain spaces or commas.

Comment: When I try this I get the error *"%%a was unexpected at this time."*

Comment: `%%a` is batch file syntax. When you enter it directly at the command line, use `%a` only (each occurrence)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a go in **python** that seems to work. Someone else may have a better answer.

I create the python file:

*docker_run.py*

```
import re
import os

myfile = 'C:/fullpath/credentials'
with open(myfile,'r') as f:
    mystr = f.read()
vals = re.findall('=[\s]*([^\n]+)',mystr)
keys = ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID','AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY','AWS_SESSION_TOKEN']
environment_vars = ''.join([' -e ' + k + '=' + v for k,v in zip(keys,vals)])
cmd = 'docker run'+environment_vars+' my-aws-container'

os.system(cmd)
```

Then from command prompt I run:

```
python docker_run.py
```

This succeeds in running docker

*(note: I tried using exec() in the final line rather than os.system(), but got the error "SyntaxError: invalid syntax")*